# How to send notifications to an user with PHP?

Tags: php, curl, notifications, facebook-php-sdk

I searched the Web everywhere to find an answer to my question, but i don't find any clear and simple answer... How to send a notification to an user with PHP ? We consider that the 'user' has installed the FB App.

I tried this code :

```
$post_data = "access_token=".$facebook->getAccessToken()."&template=My message&href=http://google.com";

$curl = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/".$user."/notifications/"); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$page = curl_exec($curl); 
curl_close($curl); 

print($page);
```

But I receive the following error message : {"error":{"message":"(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token.","type":"OAuthException","code":15}}
I don't using the right access_token ??
Thanks to help me or show me another code... :)

Answer (score 3):

Try sending notification using this format with access token as `querystring`

```
$post_data = "access_token=".$facebook->getAccessToken()."&template=My message&href=http://google.com";

$curl = curl_init(); 

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://graph.facebook.com/".$user."notifications?access_token= … &template= … &href= …"); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$page = curl_exec($curl); 
curl_close($curl); 

print($page);
```

Comment: OK thanks a lot I think it works but I don't have the permission : "The 'manage_notifications' permission is required in order to query the user's notifications."
How to add this perm to my app ? :)

Comment: the manage_notifications permission. You can turn on the “Require manage_notifications permission” migration from the About->Advanced section of your app’s settings in the Developer app. Additionally, starting on Tuesday night, you’ll be able to access a user’s notifications via the Graph API using the notifications connection on the me identifier. We’ll update thedocumentation when this launches.

Comment: I'm French and "Require manage_notifications permission" doesn't exists in "Paramètres > Advanced" section. And the field "User & Friend Permissions" in "Paramètres > Autorisations" doesn't works at all !